# JS Web file vs project directory file

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Does it matter if you reference to a file via an external link, for example a JS file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Versus downloading the file, putting it in a directory in your project and pointing to that file:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
```

I'm curious to if this even matters, is it personal preference is there a space/network component to this etc.

I usually choose to download the file and add it to my project manually in fear of if the external server were to be down or inaccessible that the file will still be available to my project - having the need to only worry about one server being down.

Any input appreciated :)

Comment: Your first script it's called CDN (Content Delivery Network), and it's useful to reduce the latency in the petitions, because CDN servers are fastest in general words.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is, or what people's preference is?

Comment: @j08691 if it's a preference, then we must close this as offtopic, huh?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry for confusion - I definitely want to know what the difference is and if there's a performance or safety side to it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - thank you, this makes perfect sense

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have a requirement that forbids you to use external sites, are useful for deliver common libraries faster than your server, at least if you don't have a NASA server ;) In some projects, you can't use them, by project requirements. For example, I was working in the past in a China project, does not have access to Google, so the fonts and the CDN used doesn't work. We need to change locally. Good luck!